# SKLearn Pipeline w/ ColumnTransformer: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to use SKLearn 0.20.2 to make a pipeline while using the new ColumnTransformer feature. My problem is that I keep getting the error:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'`

I have a column of blobs of text called, `text`. All of my other columns are numerical in nature. I'm trying to use the `Countvectorizer` in my pipeline and I think that's where the trouble is. Would much appreciate a hand with this.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
# plus other necessary modules

# mapped to column names from dataframe
numeric_features = ['hasDate', 'iterationCount', 'hasItemNumber', 'isEpic']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'))
])

# mapped to column names from dataframe
text_features = ['text']
text_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent”')),
    ('vect', CountVectorizer())
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),('text', text_transformer, text_features)]
)

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', MultinomialNB())
                     ])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.33)
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Comment: `SimpleImputer` is not intended for text. Try `text_transformer = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer())])` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyBushmanov! Now I have a new error: `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`. I'll update my snippet to remove the imputer.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov actually, I went ahead and put the problematic code back and left an answer with your instructions because it did indeed fix initial error.

Comment: As far as your latest error is concerned. Can you track down, e.g. with `fit_transform` method, which line, `preprocessor` or `clf`, produces the error?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I marked this question as answered since you did give me a solution to the error. I started a new question with details of the new error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541490/sklearn-text-and-numeric-features-with-columntransformer-has-value-error

Answer (score 1):

@SergeyBushmanov helped me diagnose the error in my title, it was caused by running `SimpleImputer` on text.

I have a further error that I'll write a new question for.