# Sklearn: Text and Numeric features with ColumnTransformer has value error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use SKLearn 0.20.2 to make a pipeline while using the new ColumnTransformer feature. My problem is that when I run my classifier: `clf.fit(x_train, y_train)` I keep getting the error:

`ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

I have a column of blocks of text called, `text`. All of my other columns are numerical in nature. I'm trying to use the Countvectorizer in my pipeline and I think that's where the trouble is. Would much appreciate a hand with this.

After I run the pipeline and I check my x_train/y_train it looks like this if helpful (omitting the row numbers that normally show in the left column, and the text column runs taller than is shown in the image).

[image]

---

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
# plus other necessary modules

# mapped to column names from dataframe
numeric_features = ['hasDate', 'iterationCount', 'hasItemNumber', 'isEpic']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'))
])

# mapped to column names from dataframe
text_features = ['text']
text_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('vect', CountVectorizer())
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),('text', text_transformer, text_features)]
)

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', MultinomialNB())
                     ])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.33)
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Comment: What is `features` and `labels` in `train_test_split`? The outcome of `features.shape` and `labels.shape`?

Answer (score 2):

Vadim is correct that if you run this code

```
numeric_features = ['hasDate', 'iterationCount', 'hasItemNumber', 'isEpic']
numeric_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')

num = numeric_transformer.fit_transform(df[numeric_features])

# num.shape  
# (3, 4)

text_features = ['text']
text_transformer = CountVectorizer()

text = text_transformer.fit_transform(df[text_features])

print(text_transformer.get_feature_names())
print(text.toarray())
```

the output will look like this.

```
['text']
[[1]]
```

This is due to some glitch in the text process that I have come across more than once.

If you define your text_features as a string rather than a one-element list

```
text_features = 'text'
text_transformer = CountVectorizer()

text = text_transformer.fit_transform(df[text_features])

print(text_transformer.get_feature_names())
print(text.toarray())`
```

Becomes this

```
['123', '16118', '17569', '456', '8779', '9480']
[[0 0 1 0 1 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Which is what you want it to be.

Putting the column name as a list makes the CountVectorizer only see one item for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you shouldn't use `Pipeline` if you need to understand or debug the code. The issue is with your `text_transformer`. The output of `numeric_transformer` is as expected:

```
# example
df = pd.DataFrame([['(0,17569)\t1\n(0,8779)\t0\n', 1, 13, 1, 0],
                   ['(0,16118)\t1\n(0,9480)\t1\n', 1, None, 0, 1],
                   ['(0,123)\t1\n(0,456)\t1\n', 1, 15, 0, 0]],
                  columns=('text', 'hasDate', 'iterationCount', 'hasItemNumber', 'isEpic'))

numeric_features = ['hasDate', 'iterationCount', 'hasItemNumber', 'isEpic']
numeric_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')

num = numeric_transformer.fit_transform(df[numeric_features])

print(num)

#[[ 1. 13.  1.  0.]
# [ 1. 14.  0.  1.]
# [ 1. 15.  0.  0.]]
```

But `text_transformer` gives you an array of shape `(1, 1)`. So, you need to figure out, how do you want to transform your `text` column:

```
text_features = ['text']
text_transformer = CountVectorizer()

text = text_transformer.fit_transform(df[text_features])

print(text_transformer.get_feature_names())
print(text.toarray())

#['text']
#[[1]]
```